# Is it possible to use RadMaskedTextBox inside an AutoCompleteBox in Silverlight / Expression Blend?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, expression-blend, maskedtextbox, autocompletebox

It's probably doable, but with my n00b skills I couldn't figure this out yet.

When I try to "Make Into Part" on the RadMaskedTextBox, Expression Blend complains that it's not a TextBox.

How can I make it to use it as a proper control part? Can I "typecast" somehow in XAML?

Thanks in advance for all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first answer is correct. While you can insert a RadMaskedTextBox into an autocomplete template (steps below), internally it wants to see a TextBox class to hook up the text changed event. The Telerik RadMaskedTextBox derives from Control instead, so the event is not hooked up.

- Drag an AutocompleteBox onto your page.
- Drag a Terlerik RadMaskedTextBox onto your page (to add the correct XML namespace for you)
- Edit the AutoComplete template in Blend to generate a local template.
- *Manually* edit the XAML template to use a RadMaskedTextBox instead of the TextBox.
- Remove the Terlerik RadMaskedTextBox

The solution would be to use another Masked edit box that does derive from TextBox and insert it using the above steps

Comment: So then the not-so-nice, but working solution could be putting the RadMaskedTextBox over the original TextBox and wiring them together in C#, so the value of the RadMaskedTextBox gets written into the TextBox as the user types?

Wait, but then I`d also have to wire things the other way too, so if something is chosen from the popup that`ll be sent to the RadMaskedTextBox :/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `RadMaskedTextBox` because it doesn't derive from `TextBox`.  The code inside `AutoCompleteBox` specifies that this part must at least derive from `TextBox`.

Comment: Would it be really complicated to customise that code? I`d expect RadMaskedTextBox to behave very similarly to TextBox, so maybe there`s not that much work to do there? How would you set out to do this?